# GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2032

Tags: django, php-mongodb

i'm trying to install Fang of Mongo, i did all the steps required but whe i try to go to the http page i have got this error message:

```
muratalina@muratalina-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~/Documents/Fang-of-Mongo/fangofmongo$ python ./manage.py runserver
    Validating models...
    0 errors found
    Django version 1.4.3, using settings 'fangofmongo.settings'
    Development server is running at "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    [29/Jan/2013 12:36:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2032
```

when i go to "`http://127.0.0.1:8000/fangofmongo/`" page i have got this error [image]

Comment: Try updating their views because sometimes there are functions their that are not use.

Answer (score 1):

The base URL for [Fang-of-Mongo](https://github.com/Fiedzia/Fang-of-Mongo) is:

`(r'^fangofmongo/', include('fangofmongo.fom.urls')),`

This means that you will need to navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/fangofmongo`.

There is no base URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` defined - so it will 404.

EDIT: Also Fang-of-Mongo appears to have gone 3 years, at least on Github, without an update - so you will most likely encounter other issues with the project running on Django 1.4.3.

Comment: i see, thanks any way :) i'll look for another solution instead of fang of mongo

Comment: The edit that you made with the `json_util` error is because of a `pymongo` module. Do you have `pymongo` installed? `json_util` is deprecated and has been changed to this: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0.1/api/pymongo/json_util.html

Comment: yes, i've pymongo installed. what should i do to change son_util? change smth in json_util.py?

Comment: Add these two imports instead: `import bson` and `import bson.json_util`. If you insist on using this deprecated project though, I'd suggest you fork it from this person as they seem to have made at least some of the necessary changes: https://github.com/larroy/Fang-of-Mongo

Comment: And change your views to the corresponding change in the imports.

Comment: tnx for help, i couldn't install Fang of mongo, but i tried to install rock mongo and it's worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported the include function in the urls.py, else add "from django.urls import include"

Here is how to Include another URLconf (in urls.py file)

Including another URLconf

```
1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path

2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
```